# Download a file of size 1 GB using AWS Lambda

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, ftp

I am trying to download a file from FTP server using .Net core 3.1 in AWS Lambda. But, maximum disk space available to a lambda function is 512 MB. Is there any way to download the file of size 1 GB in AWS Lambda?

Comment: Uh... you could probably stream it to an S3 bucket?

Answer (score 4):

For large files in a Lambda AWS has [recently added support for EFS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-efs-for-aws-lambda-in-your-serverless-applications/).

By using an EFS mount your Lambda(s) have access to persistent storage that will scale elasticly as your application demands it.

This will also last past any cold starts, new versions or across multiple Lambdas (and EC2 instances) at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I need to process the files after downloading them. It is really great if you can provide some code sample.

Comment: You can process these files after you download them, when you create the EFS mount you can bind as if its a local folder on disk for your Lambda. You could then access any files that exist in `/efs`. Regarding examples there are a few that are included in the link I have attached, if you have any questions after reading that I'd be happy to try and assist :)

Comment: Those examples are not useful in my case. To proceed with EFS approach, I still need to download the file from FTP server and upload it back to EFS. But, because of the lambda memory limitations, I can't download large files.

Comment: When I create an EFS mount on lambda, will lambda automatically use `/efs` path to store the data instead of `/tmp` folder?

Comment: You would need to specify to use the `/efs` path wherever you previously specified as `/tmp`